# Combinatorics chess pawns placement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, chessboard

How many ways can one place $8$ pawns on a $4$x$4$ chess board such that each row and each column contains exactly $2$ pawns?

I figured a brute-force way where I go row by row placing $2$ pawns each and tracking the number of ways in which the column criteria are met.

Is there a more elegant (shorter or better structured) approach? What I mean is given we need to place $2n^2$ pawns in a $4n^2$ square board with each row column containing exactly $n$ pawns, this approach won't be scalable since I can't use the above result recursively either.

Comment: This is a standard trick. Consider the graph $G$, where the vertices are the $n$ rows and $n$ columns, and there is an edge between row $x$ and column $y$ if there is a pawn at cell $(x,y)$. What does your condition impose on $G$?

Comment: @StevenMai - From what I interpret, $G$ is bipartite, and each node in set C connects with exactly $2$ ($n$ in general) nodes in set R. How do I proceed from there? I'm sorry not, I'm not very well versed with graph theory, but want to know this solution further. Seems quite interesting!

Comment: Every vertice has degree 2, so the graph is a bunch of cycles. The cycles must be even length since the graph is bipartite, and also size at least 4. If n is 4, then you must have either two cycles of length 4,or a cycle of length 8. For a cycle of length 8, there are 24 ways to order the rows and 24 ways to order  the columns, but you must divide by 8, since each pair of ordering is counted 8 times. The other case can be counted in a similar way

Comment: @StevenMai thanks, this helps!